# UIScrollView and Page Control, Page Control Disrupting View

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, uipagecontrol

So, I know its been done many times before, but I am building a ImageViewer with a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl. I am building it in Swift. Yet I have come across a issue which I can't seem to diagnose. I have a interesting setup to minimize long pages of code by splitting a view into containers. One for a tableview, the other for paging images. Here is a image of the storyboard. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAyXQ.jpg So in the first container view, it is a simple UIViewController with a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl. I can confirm that the UIPageControl is not in the view hierarchy of the UIScrollView. Now here is the code I used to setup everything.

```
import UIKit

//Set Image Array
var imagelist: String[] = ["Home Image 1.png", "info.png"]

//Set Page Numbers
var numpages = imagelist.count

class HomeImageView: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    //IBOutlets & Propertys
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView

    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup Page Control
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numpages
        pageControl.currentPage = 0

        //Setup Scroll View
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.bounces = true;
        scrollView.scrollsToTop = false
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(numpages), scrollView.frame.size.height)


        }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


        //Setup UIViews with Images
        for var z = 0; z < numpages; z++ {

            let mainFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(z), 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)

            var image: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: mainFrame)

            image.image = UIImage(named: imagelist[z])

            image.clipsToBounds = true

            image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

            scrollView.addSubview(image)

    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollview: UIScrollView) {

        var pageSize: Float = Float(scrollView.bounds.size.width)
        var page: Float = floorf((Float(scrollview.contentOffset.x) - pageSize / 2.0) / pageSize) + 1
        // Bound page limits
        if (page >= Float(numpages)) {
            page = Float(numpages) - 1;
        } else if (page < 0) {
            page = 0;
        }

        pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
        println(pageControl.currentPage)
    }
  }
}
```

So with that out of the way, here is the problem. When I run it, it does not do exactly what I expected. The simulator starts like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAqkv.jpg and I can move the view around outside the bounds of the image.. Yet when I change the view hierarchy so that UIPageControl is behind the UIScrollView (Basically Removing it). The problem disappears completely. Aligned and allowing movement only in the bounds like I want. I don't know why the UIScrollView would react to the UIPageControl when it is outside its view hierarchy. Thanks for any assistance.